# How to push element in array inside a key/value object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a structured payload like the example below:

```
var payload = [
{
  "firstService-2xx": 0.1,
  "firstService-4xx": 0,
  "firstService-5xx": 1.2,
  "secondService-2xx": 5.4,
  "secondService-4xx": 1,
  "secondService-5xx": 0.2
},
{
  "firstService-2xx": 10.4,
  "firstService-4xx": 0.3,
  "firstService-5xx": 0.2,
  "secondService-2xx": 9.8,
  "secondService-4xx": 0.1,
  "secondService-5xx": 0.7
}
]
```

Then i have an array which contains the list of service names:

```
var services = ["firstService", "secondService"]
```

Finally I initialized an object which should be the structure of the result:

```
var obj = {
   twoHundred: [],
   fourHundred: [],
   fiveHundred: []
};
var finalResult = {
    "firstService" : obj,
    "secondService": obj
}
```

The expected result of my function should be:

```
finalResult = {
   "firstService": {
      twoHundred: [0.1, 10.4],
      fourHundred: [0, 0.3],
      fiveHundred: [1.2, 0.2]
    },
   "secondService": {
      twoHundred: [5.4, 9.8],
      fourHundred: [1, 0.1],
      fiveHundred: [0.2, 0.7]
    }
```

But what I get is that all values for each "code" (2xx,4xx,5xx) are pushed into all respective arrays, even of unwanted services.

```
payload.forEach(element => {                          
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(element)) {
    services.forEach(service => {
        if (service == key.slice(0,-4)) {
            if (key.includes("2xx")){
                finalResult[service].twoHundred.push(value);
            } else if (key.includes("4xx")){
                finalResult[service].fourHundred.push(value);
            } else if (key.includes("5xx")) {
                finalResult[service].fiveHundred.push(value);
            }
        }
    })
}
})
```

Doing some debugging it seems related to push, the rest of the checks work. I also tried in the form finalResult[service]["fiveHundred"].push(value) but the result doesn't change.
I also tried changing the code, the loops but in the end I always get this (wrong) result:

```
{
 firstService: {
   twoHundred: [ 0.1, 5.4, 10.4, 9.8 ],
   fourHundred: [ 0, 1, 0.3, 0.1 ],
   fiveHundred: [ 1.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7 ]
 },
 secondService: {
   twoHundred: [ 0.1, 5.4, 10.4, 9.8 ],
   fourHundred: [ 0, 1, 0.3, 0.1 ],
   fiveHundred: [ 1.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7 ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only *one* object here:

```
var obj = {
  twoHundred: [],
  fourHundred: [],
  fiveHundred: []
};
```

And multiple references to that *one* object:

```
var finalResult = {
  "firstService" : obj,
  "secondService": obj
}
```

Regardless of which reference you use, when you push a value to an array on that *one* object, that object now has that value in one of its arrays.  Any reference to that object will see that value, because they reference the same object.

It sounds like you want to use *two* objects, for example:

```
var finalResult = {
  "firstService" : {
    twoHundred: [],
    fourHundred: [],
    fiveHundred: []
  },
  "secondService": {
    twoHundred: [],
    fourHundred: [],
    fiveHundred: []
  }
}
```

That way any changes made to one of them aren't reflected in the other, because they're two different objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was so focused on the function and the end goal that I forgot the basics :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result using `reduce` and few helper functions.

```js
const inputServices = [
  {
    "firstService-2xx": 0.1,
    "firstService-4xx": 0,
    "firstService-5xx": 1.2,
    "secondService-2xx": 5.4,
    "secondService-4xx": 1,
    "secondService-5xx": 0.2
  },
  {
    "firstService-2xx": 10.4,
    "firstService-4xx": 0.3,
    "firstService-5xx": 0.2,
    "secondService-2xx": 9.8,
    "secondService-4xx": 0.1,
    "secondService-5xx": 0.7
  }
];



const groupedServices = {
  "firstService": {
    twoHundred: [],
    fourHundred: [],
    fiveHundred: []
  },
  "secondService": {
    twoHundred: [],
    fourHundred: [],
    fiveHundred: []
  }
};

const codeMap = {
  '2': 'two',
  '4': 'four',
  '5': 'five'
};

// returns code name in plain English insted of xx5 etc.
const getEngKey = (code) => `${codeMap[code.replace(/xx/g, '')[0]]}Hundred`;


// Use spread operator to populate object with inputServices values. They are grouped by serviceKey, and every serviceKey value is grouped by engKey
const getServiceResult = (result, [key, value]) => {
  const [serviceKey, code] = key.split('-');
  const engKey = getEngKey(code);
  return {
...result,
[serviceKey]: {
  ...result[serviceKey],
  [engKey]: [...(result[serviceKey][engKey] || []), value]
}
  };
};

//applies getServiceResult to every object in inputServices  
const outputServices= inputServices.reduce((result, item) => {
  return Object.entries(item).reduce(getServiceResult, result);
}, groupedServices);



console.log(outputServices);
```